# Nested UITableViews like Snapchat's search

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I am trying to create a view that contains nested table views and collection views, very similar to Snapchat's new search UI:

[image]

At first glance, I would say the best way would be to simply use one table view and have a set of different table view cells that fill different purposes. One that contains a collection view (for the discover section) and then just create the rest of the UI using sections and custom cells.

However, there is one fundamental issue with this. I want to allow horizontal scrolling between different table views within sections. Snapchat are also doing this, see the pager above the table views. I could create a similar layout from creating a custom cell that contains a horizontal scroll view (or a page controller). But unless I let the inner table view have the same content size as frame size (and force all cells to be dequeued at the same time) I will end up with two different scroll views, acting independently of each other.

Another issues would arise from allowing the table views to lazy load, and the fact that table views could have different content heights.

Any ideas as to how they might be doing this?